# Installing a persistant Ubuntu OS onto a USB without re-installing it to the hard-drive

Tags: system-installation, usb

I have tried uunetbootin and mkusb, to try to install Ubuntu 18.0.3 onto a usb, as an OS, not as an install disk.

With uunetbootin, it just over-writes the Ubuntu on my laptop, and installs an 'install' disk onto the usb, even when i select *only* the usb.

With mkusb, it just freezes when I choose the usb as the target disk to install to, with persistence, and choose the live install dvd of 18.04.3 in the dvd drive as the source disk.

The only way I have been able to do it, is by locking the hard-drive in the bios (intentionally entering the wrong password on start-up), and then F12 booting from the Install DVD. Then when Ubuntu loads, clicking on install, and choosing the usb as the target device.

Ubuntu gives an error message of being unable to write/close the hard-drive, which I just click 'ignore', and after 3 times of this message, it installs a perfect OS with persistence onto the usb.

Works for me on a Dell laptop, but surely there must be a *easier,simpler* way ??

Thanks,

vedaal

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. What you described is a full install of Ubuntu on the USB, not a persistent Live USB. This is a question answer site. Please read the site [help](https://askubuntu.com/help) for information about what kind of questions are appropriate for this site.

Comment: Unetbooting and mkusb can create *installers*, but cannot install full systems. There's a big difference between an installer and a full system. Only the installers can install full systems. You are correct that you need two flash drives (one for the installer, one for the installed), and that you must carefully prevent the installer from installing onto the hard drive. Most folks DO want the install on the hard drive - USB installs are a bit of a corner case.

Comment: Both Unetbootin and mkusb create live drives without or with persistence. The do not create an installed system. From which drive did you boot, when you were running mkusb? And what did you want to achieve? It is possible to use a DVD disk as source, but it will be very slow because it is a slow medium. Maybe so slow that you thought that the process froze. -- Do you want help, or are you happy with the method that you describe at the end of you question?

Comment: I do want to find a better way.

Comment: I wanted to install a 'travel' full Ubuntu system on a 256 gb USB. 
The problem was, that whenever I tried to do this, the Installation would overwrite the system on my laptop. 
I first tried doing this from my Ubuntu 18.04, with a USB as the target drive, and the DVD install disk, as the source drive. It was slow, but didn't freeze, and even though it presented me with the hard drive as the first choice, I changed it to the USB.  It still overwrote my hard drive, and only installed an install disk onto the USB. 
How can a full system onto a USB without overwriting the hard drive? 
TIA

Comment: Yes, this link by Sudodus solves the problem.  The Ubuntu source install dvd or usb, apparently *must* think that it can only install into *one* target, i.e the usb.  If it finds any hard-drive target, it defaults to install to the hard-drive.  I found it not easy to disconnect the hard-drive from my laptop, but functionally accomplished the same by making the hard-drive inaccessible by locking it.